# Worksheet_Change Loop Causes Excel to stop Responding

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA script so that when the cell value is 'N/A', it offsets one cell to the right and writes 'N/A' as well. The script works, but it causes the Excel to stop responding. I want it to do this every time a change is made to the cell range so i made it a "Worksheet_Change." My thought (which I might and probably will be wrong for)is that it has to do it for every change made to the sheet causing the program to "burn out."

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rng As Range
Dim i As Long
Set rng = Range("E267:E1000")
For Each cell In rng
    'test if cell is empty
    If cell.Value = "N/A" Then
        'write to adjacent cell
        cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "N/A"
    End If
Next  
End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't simply use a formula (`=IF(E267="N/A","N/A","")` for this?

Comment: You would be in an infinite loop, you are always changing the sheet in the code.

Comment: I would presume , that N/A is a result of a formula. Worksheet_change events only work with Physical changes, not a change performed by a formula.

Comment: I posted a solution to the infinite loop, but are you sure you need to recalculate the entire column when a change is made? Wouldnt you just want to check the value of the cell that is changing?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad I want to avoid using the formula due to at that point, the cell not actually being blank if E267 doesn't = N/A

Comment: @Fabricio Martinez the fomula I suggested gives a value of `""` if `E267` is not `N/A` so the cell is blank, though it does contain a formula. Why is this a problem?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad let's just say that the other's using this excel file are not as proficient and might break something when they double click the cell and see a hidden formula.

Comment: Unless they also need to write to that column, you could always just protect it to prevent people playing around with the formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are physically changing a cell, you can target the range of cells being changed.
For example, the below code kicks in every time you physically change a cell in the specified range.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub    ' this stops code error if more than one cell is changed at once

    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("E267:E1000")) Is Nothing Then    ' indicates the Target range
        If Target.Value = "N/A" Then
            Target.Offset(, 1) = Target.Value
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you must use VBA for this, you can try this. Disable events in your loop when changes are being made to be sure you are not getting stuck in a infinite loop. Also, if your range is dynamic I highly recommend replacing your lower bound (E1000) with a dynamic variable that tracks the last row in your data set to minimize the number of loops your macro runs.

For instance, if your macro is on a sheet, you can use this as the lower bound in your range, which would then be `set rng=Range("E267:E" & LROW)`

```
Dim LROW as Long
LROW = Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

Macro

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rng As Range
Dim i As Long
Set rng = Range("E267:E1000")
For Each cell In rng
Application.Enable Events = False
    'test if cell is empty
    If cell.Value = "N/A" Then
        'write to adjacent cell
        cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "N/A"
    End If
Application.EnableEvents=True
Next  
End Sub
```

Comment: @daveexcel's formula works perfectly. However, I wanted to know how I would integrate

                 Dim LROW as Long
                 LROW = Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 

into the macro.